# Hide the column names in DT::datatable()

Tags: r, dt

Is there any way to hide the column names when using the `DT::datatable()`

That returns now data at all:

```
empty<-data.frame(c("a","d","d"),c("s","d","d"))
library(DT)
datatable(empty,colnames = F)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
datatable(empty, colnames = c("", ""))
```

**EDIT**

```
datatable(empty, colnames = rep("", ncol(empty)))
```

To make the code more robust

Comment: this is cool.exactly what I needed. Do you if I can skip those up-down arrows next to the column names as well?

Comment: `datatable(empty, colnames = rep("", ncol(empty)),options=list(ordering=F))`

Comment: tnx a lot great!

Answer (score 15):

Instead of setting blank column names, you can completely remove the header in this way:

```
library(DT)

datatable(head(iris), 
          options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(
              "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
              "  $(thead).remove();",
              "}")
          )
)
```

Comment: @Laurent you should definitely write a book, you're the most knowledgeable person I've seen online in regards of Shiny.

Comment: Neat. Works beautifully

Comment: by the way, this solution is causing a side undesired effect. The datatable it generates doesn't respect the UI column=n format. For example, on my end my table should follow the ui parameter column(10,...) but when I use the suggested code above, the table shrinks considerably.